# Error "String subscript out of range"

Tags: c++, string

I meet error "String subscript out of range" when run these codes

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    ifstream in("_start.txt");
    ofstream out("_end.txt");

    string str;
    while (getline(in, str))
    {
        if ((str[0] != '/') && (str[1] != '/'))
            out << str << endl;     
    }

    //getline(in, str);
    //if ((str[0] != '/') && (str[1] != '/'))
        //out << str << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

File _start.txt is like this

```
//<3403> 「それじゃまるで…俺おまえのライバルみたいじゃんか…」
<3403> 「It's like...we were actually rivals or something...」
<3403> 「Giống như...chúng ta là đối thủ thật sự hay sao ấy...」

//<3404> 井上
<3404> Inoue

//<3405> 「きっとね」
<3405> 「I'm sure we were.」
<3405> 「Tôi tin là thế.」
```

My purpose is to check 2 character at start of each line if have "//-character" will be ignored. Then I keep checking 6 characters at start of each line with same format

```
<[number with at least 4 characters, so number 1 will be written 0001]>
```

and this line's number is bigger than previous line's number 1. So if this line's number is equal

```
Add "//-character" at start of previous line
```

or bigger previous line's number 2, 3 or 4,... (larger than 1) will be fixed.

It is a long way so I started with mini-purpose is to print all lines except lines with "//-character" at beginning and I meet this error. If I do without loop, everything is fine with first line but when I include loop, error appears.

Comment: What makes you sure that accessing `str[1]` is validly inside the actual bounds?

Comment: If I debug with "Step over" in VS without loop, at "str" value VS show first line, if i do with loops but without "if statement", VS show each line after each loop. I think is fine if I add "if" in loops but error appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if((str[0] != '/') && (str[1] != '/'))
//                 ^^
//         btw, this should be ||
```

will invoke *undefined behavior* on empty lines and lines with single `/` and no other characters.
Add this check ([short-circuit evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799072/c-short-circuiting-of-booleans)):

```
if(str.length() < 2 || (str[0] != '/') || (str[1] != '/'))
```

Read it as:

> If `str` is shorter than two characters, we already know that it won't contain `//` at the beginning. Otherwise, do the check (which is only possible for longer strings).

Using [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), it is the same as:

```
if(!(str.length() >= 2 && str[0] == '/' && str[1] == '/'))
```

which might be easier to understand. Read it as:

> First, check if `str` has at least two characters. If it does, check if the first two are `//`. Execute the code below if this condition yields `false`.

It is also possible to use `std::string::substr` to achieve shorter code:

```
if(str.length() < 2 || str.substr(0, 2) != "//")
```

or

```
if(!(str.length() >= 2 && str.substr(0, 2) == "//"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm new with C++ so  I miss the case empty line.

Comment: note: since C++11 the length check is not actually necessary; `str[str.size()]` is defined as referring to a read-only null terminator stored somewhere, and the short-circuiting will prevent `str[1]` being tried if `str[0]` were indeed the null terminator