# Stacks in C++: Runtime error if the "or" condition is switched

Tags: c++, stack

I have often found this weird while using Stacks in C++ and I'm not sure what the exact root of the problem is. It would be better explained with a snippet of the code: (I am trying to get the minimum value of a stack and pushing/popping etc. as usual)

```
class MinStack {
private:
    stack<int> ans;
    stack<int> min_collector;

public:
    void push(int x) {
        ans.push(x);
        if (min_collector.empty() || getMin()>=x) {
            min_collector.push(x);
        }
    }

    void pop() {
        if (ans.top()==getMin()) {
            min_collector.pop();
        }
        ans.pop();
    }

    int top() {
        return ans.top();
    }

    int getMin() {
        return min_collector.top();
    }
```

};

The above code works fine. However, in the push(int x) function, if I edit the "if" condition like this:

```
(getMin()>=x  || min_collector.empty())
```

I get a runtime error, has anyone else faced this issue? Why should the order in a "or" condition matter?

Comment: What do you think happens on `min_collector.top()` when the stack is empty?

Comment: "Why should the order in a "or" condition matter?" because there is short circuit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799072/c-short-circuiting-of-booleans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These conditions are evaluated from left to right, and execution aborts once the first term has returned `true`.

For logic `&&` execution aborts once the first term has returned `false`.

You get a runtime error because it is illegal to attempt to access the `top()` element of a stack when it's empty - there is no top element.

Comment: Thanks, I was not familiar with the "short circuit" principle.