# Using nested if statements vs logical operator && in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, if-statement, logic, logical-operators

Let us say I have an integer array representing the chess pieces on a board;

```
int board[8][8];
```

In my chess game, I am currently coding a generator function that will return an *integer vector* of all legal moves.

Naturally, I will be using **if statements**

I am at a point where I need to check a certain element in the board **relative** to a piece on the board

For example, If I have a pawn piece;

```
board[row][col] == 'p';
```

I need to generate `[row+1][col]`, `[row+2][col]` and in some cases if it can attack a piece, a change in column too.

But if a piece is on any edge of the `board`, `board[row+1][col]` will return be **index out of range**

For that reason I need an extra if statement.

My question is, shall i use:

```
if (pieceisnotonedge && board[row+1][col] == 0)
```

or

```
if (pieceisnotonedge)
{
    if (board[row+1][col] == 0)
}
```

For the first example, if `pieceisnotonedge` returns `false`, will it also check the next condition? Because if it does, then I am in trouble.

Comment: The answer to this question depends on the AND operator. Is it a built-in operator or a user-defined overload? The behavior is different.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but for pawn moves you don't have to check `row + 1`. A pawn can never be on the 8th rank; `row + 1` is always valid.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. Number one: Starting stages of the game so i did not add pawn promotion. number two was it also applies to a column. That is if a pawn is on the horizontal edge i dont need to check if board[row+1][col+1] if a piece is present. And the same rule applies for all the pieces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For the first example, if pieceisnotonedge returns false, will it also check the next condition?

No. It will "short-circuit" because if the first condition is false, checking the conditions after it is unnecessary. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628526/is-short-circuiting-logical-operators-mandated-and-evaluation-order) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799072/c-short-circuiting-of-booleans).

This is guranteed by the [C++ standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.log.and):

> **7.6.14**
>
> ... && guarantees left-to-right evaluation: the second operand is not evaluated if the first operand is false.

Note that, for `||` this is opposite, that is, if the first condition is "true", then checking the conditions afterwards is unnecessary

> Shall i use; or...

Both are same, if you have a short if statement (with only two conditions), I would suggest using the first approach. In terms of efficiency there is no difference and you can verify this by looking at the generated assembly for both cases on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/hf8Gsb)

Comment: Thank you for this! is there any difference in its effeciency, that means, is there any difference in the time taken for both the examples, because it can perform the generator function well more than 50,000 times in my chess engine!

Comment: No. There will be no difference at all. The efficiency will be exactly the same

Comment: @AryanParekh If you are in doubt, you can try both on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/) and compare the generated assembly. Even if you do not read assembly naturally a "pessimization" will usually be quite obvious simply based on the amount of code generated.

Answer (score 5):

> For the first example, if `pieceisnotonedge` returns `false`, will it also
> check the next condition?

**No, it will not**. Because the build-in [logical operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical) do **short-circuiting**. From *cppreference.com*:

> Builtin operators `&&` and `||` perform short-circuit evaluation (**do not**
> **evaluate the second operand if the result is known after evaluating**
> **the first**), but overloaded operators behave like a regular function
> calls and always evaluate both operands

Therefore, in

```
if (pieceisnotonedge && board[row+1][col] == 0)
```

if the `pieceisnotonedge` is `false`, the second will not be evaluated. Therefore, having a nested `if`s is redundant, and you can go with the first version.

Comment: Noting that this question is tagged C++, the short-circuiting by operators `&&` and `||` does not occur for user-defined overloads of `operator&&()` and `operator||()`.    If such overloads are provided and called,  then an expression of the form `a && b` or of `a || b` WILL evaluate both `a` and `b`, rather than short-circuiting if `a` is true.

Comment: @Peter Of course, it will. I have only emphasized the sentence, which is relevant to the question (Assuming that the OP is not overloading them). However, it is there in the citation, what I have added. One should read it completely.

Comment: I am confused as I am new to the language, should I use it, in c++

Comment: @AryanParekh Of course, you can. In C++ one can also [overload `operator&&`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25913237/is-there-actually-a-reason-why-overloaded-and-dont-short-circuit).  Peter was mentioning that in case you [have overloaded the `operator&&`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators), in the code, the behaviour is different/ order of evaluation is not guaranteed, since it behaves like a normal function call, and will be evaluating both conditions (This is same for `operator||` overloading). I hope, you have not overloaded the `operator&&` in your code.

Answer (score 2):

For the shown code there is no difference, both `board[row+1][col] == 0` are only evaluated if `pieceisnotonedge` is `true`.

If you should use one or the other, cannot be said be in general, as it depends on other factors (like semantic, readability, …) too.

If you e.g. want to have an action that it done if either `pieceisnotonedge` or `board[row+1][col] == 0` is false, then you probably would use `&&`, because then you can write:

```
if (pieceisnotonedge && board[row+1][col] == 0) {
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

with your other style you would need to write:

```
if (pieceisnotonedge){
    if (board[row+1][col] == 0) {
      // do something else
    }
} else {
   // do something else
}
```

In general, your first aim should be to have readable code. While `pieceisnotonedge && board[row+1][col] == 0` easy to read, more complex expressions might not be. So you would decide that on a case by case basis, if you want to use one expression or multiple `if`.

Answer (score 1):

> For the first example, if pieceisnotonedge returns false, will it also check the next condition?

No. It will stop immediately after `pieceisnotonedge` is evaluated to false. There is no subsequent check for the remainder condition `board[row+1][col] == 0`

You can use nested `if` as the second code as well - no difference. It's just a matter of what code would look clearer.

Comment: not really in this case it does not matter but if you do `if (a && b && c)` then there is no guarantee it will be evaluated in order `a,b,c` and also no guarantee the execution will stop on first false ... so if conditions are not "order" safe (like array range checks) it should be nested `if`s and if the conditions are safe it can be both versions....

Comment: @Spektre source please?

Comment: experience in past (like 10 years ago)... on MCU: GCC U-Keil and x86 BCC32  (BCB 4,5)... However newer versions might behave differently